# get last 5 records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app to learn RoR, I want to get the last x (say 5) records in a list.

Currently I get all using

```
<% @business_partner.received_documents.each do |document| %>
```

Looking at documentation and SC posts, I tried using this code below, yet get an empty list.

```
<% @business_partner.received_documents.last(5) do |document| %>
```

what should I use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order `received_documents` by the creation date and take 5 last:

```
@business_partner.received_documents.order(:created_at).limit(5)
```

To get 5 newest ones you'd do:

```
@business_partner.received_documents.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
```

## EDIT

The problem with this

```
@business_partner.received_documents.last(5) do |document|
```

is that you actually **do not** iterate over the collection, thus no output is shown.

Use `each`:

```
@business_partner.received_documents.last(5).each do |document|
```

Answer (score 1):

You Forget to User `each` In Your Code

```
<% @business_partner.received_documents.last(5).each do |document| %>
```